# Javascript Regex returning 0

Tags: javascript, regex

[image: Javascript Regex Error]

As you can see, the e-mail should be valid. Regardless of what I enter, z returns null. Am I using the wrong syntax, entirely?

How do I make this regex return true?
Thanks!

```
function emailValidate() {
var x = document.forms["creation"]["emailCreation"].value;
var y = x.length;
var z = x.match(" /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/");
var_dump(z);
var_dump(x);
```

Comment: i think you need to remove the double quotes in `x.match()`

Comment: Anivash - that worked, partially. It turned z into an array, and if (z == true) { } does not work, the same for != or !== NULL. Any more advice? Thanks!

Comment: Your regex works.  Show the code that doesn't work.

Comment: dan111: `if (z !== NULL) { document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = "test7"; }` --- I also used `!= NULL`, and `== true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not actually wanting to get matches and are just wanting to test that the email fits the regular express than use the [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method of the RegExp object and pass the string you want to test against.

```js
var emailReg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

function emailValidate() {
    var x = document.forms["creation"]["emailCreation"].value;
    var y = x.length;
    var z = emailReg.test(x);
    alert(z);
    return z;
}
```

```html
<form name="creation" onsubmit="return emailValidate()">
   <input name="emailCreation" type="email" />
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Regex is valid according to my test here: http://regexr.com/39on5

The issue I see is that the `.match()` method should takes a Regex. You have passed a Regex inside a string.

The solution is to destringify (takes the quotes off the beginning and end):

```
var z = x.match(/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/);
```

This will return an array of matches, per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```
["admin@website.com", "admin", "admin", undefined, undefined, "website.com", undefined, "website.com", "website."]
```

How you want to further validate using this array is up to you. Here is a suggestion on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript). Hope that helps!

Comment: PS, I didn't address it because it wasn't part of your core question, but is there are reason you're using var_dump? This doesn't exist in JavaScript, which has its own garbage collection.

Comment: Adam, yes: If you're refering to console.file(?), it's a massive pain to use. I found a script that mimics var_dump, and added that for testing. :)